# .NET Regex lookahead custom line continuation

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I am attempting to parse a file line-by-line in powershell, and then sort it alphabetically according to the line's text. The only caveat is that a line that begins with "..." should be considered as a continuation of the prior line.

**Example Input:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor. sit amet
ne his posse convenire corrumpit
meliore suavitate ex mel
...Affert quidam docendi vix ex
...in adhuc dolore his
Fabulas scriptorem ex ius
...Nam ad vero ferri placerat
Lorem homero aperiam qui ne
...Qui esse altera 
...recusabo no
..eu eros mediocrem
mediocritatem mel. Novum fabulas ei sed.
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Fabulas scriptorem ex ius
...Nam ad vero ferri placerat
Lorem homero aperiam qui ne
...Qui esse altera 
...recusabo no
...eu eros mediocrem
Lorem ipsum dolor. sit amet
mediocritatem mel. Novum fabulas ei sed. 
meliore suavitate ex mel
...Affert quidam docendi vix ex
...in adhuc dolore his
ne his posse convenire corrumpit
```

I'm able to get the first line continuation with this regex, but not able to recognize the 2nd, 3rd, ... nth line continuations...
`.*(\r\n\.\.\.)?.*\r\n`
[image]

Anyone able to help me adjust to regex to resolve this?

Comment: No one can help you if you do not show your PS code. Please share it to see how you are getting the input text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the comment, I should have made it more clear that the question was mostly about the regex, not the PS Code. The answers below were sufficient.  For others interested in the ps code, I am simple using `Get-Content` with the `-Raw` option to preserve lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than making the `\r\n\.\.\.` optional, you need to make the entire continuation (i.e. `\r\n\.\.\..*` optional (but with possibly more than one occurrence). You can do that by modifying the regex to this:

```
.*(?:[\r\n]+\.\.\..*)*[\r\n]+
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Pj5ArY/4/)

Note that since regex101 doesn't see a `\r` character at the end of line, I had to replace `\r\n` with `[\r\n]+` to make this work there. Either should work in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
^.*(?:\n*\.{3}.*)*$|^.*$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/O6r0lS/1/)